# method `localeCompare` Method cannot be called on mixed

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I am trying to sort an object by its value :
Object is of the form :

> { "1" : "Box", "2" : "Ball", "6": "Apple"}

```
function getItemsSortedByValue() {
  return Object.entries(InputObjetc).sort(
    ([label1, value1], [label2, value2]) => {
      return(
        (value1).localeCompare(value2)
      );
    },
  );
}
```

I am getting this Flow error :

> call of method `localeCompare` Method cannot be called on mixed

Following returns a string:

> typeof(value1); //returns a string

How can I resolve this ?

Comment: I've just tried and it's working.

Comment: **Note:** Your code could be shorted to this: `return Object.entries(InputObjetc).sort( ([label1, value1], [label2, value2]) => value1.localeCompare(value2) )`. Not a solution though.

Comment: it returns an array with all entries ([key, value]), without just an array with the values.

Comment: The above link explains the problem and general solution. For your specific case, this seems to work: `((Object.entries(InputObjetc): any): Array<[string, string]>).sort` https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVBjOA7AzgFzAElsAHAV3wHkAjAKwFN8MAuMAbzAG0CAnAS2wBzALps+goWAC+YALwcwAIgCMSsGyUAhOAA8lAGmUAmdZq0BDGDEPKAbEs0BBUqRgN10gNzoo5bBj4-DhgQkxE+AwAtrgAynC8kQAmWgCeAGpW5AwAFACUHKhgYLxM5LzYYDk5tIyBAHQM2PgCDLg5JBTU9EwYeWwW2Kn9YE68vBapADw8LZJGEsIiAHx59bgJ+DlFxVVcMBY0DDAqRgBuWQwqIkb7h8fG55fGIgVyy4W7u6X45djbXy+OQuMGyKjW8AwVgYAGE4FFSBZSsDnnkdl88j4vtIDDtMahpOgsHg4O56vAhDkwvgItE4psGCkMpd8pigA

Comment: @JordanRunning Thanks alot. That solved the problem for me :D

Comment: omg I had your solution was about to post when got marked as dupYou can't sort objects in any meaningful sense. However, you can sort a Map!

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->

<!-- language: lang-js -->

    var obj = {
      "1": "Box",
      "2": "Ball",
      "6": "Apple"
    };
    var map = new Map()
    for (let i in obj) {
      map.set(i, obj[i])
    }
    var mapSort = new Map([...map.entries()].sort((a, b) => a[1].localeCompare(b[1])));
    console.log(...mapSort)

<!-- end snippet -->